# How to import data to an empty SQL server table avoiding duplicates in the source data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, bulkinsert

I am trying to import data into an empty SQL server table, avoiding duplicates that exist in the source data.

Currently I am doing a bulk insert into a temp table, and then copying the data across using:

```
INSERT INTO Actual_table
SELECT * FROM Temp_table
```

So the Temp_table and Actual_table have the exact same structure, the only difference is that on the PK field on the Actual_table, I have set up the Temp_table with a UNIQUE identifier, and set it to ignore duplicates:

```
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (Col1) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
```

In other words:

```
Actual_table

Col1 (PK)    Col2

Temp_table

Col1 (Unique, ignore duplicates)   Col2
```

The Actual_table is empty when we start this process, and the duplicates to be avoided are only on the PK field (not DISTINCT on the whole row, in other words).

I have no idea if this is the best way to achieve this, and comments/suggestions would be appreciated.

Just to flesh out my thoughts further:

1. Should I rather import straight to the actual table, adding the IGNORE_DUP_KEY contraint before importing, and then removing it (is this even possible)?
2. Do I not set up the Temp_table with the IGNORE_DUP_KEY constraint (which makes the bulk import faster), and then tweak the copying across code to ignore the duplicates? If this is a good idea, could someone please show me the syntax to achieve this.

I am using SQL server 2014.

Comment: The way you are going it is is not bad.  Have you considered cleaning up the data on the front end before the import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table is initially empty, then you just remove the duplicates when you load:

```
INSERT INTO Actual_table
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM Temp_table;
```

If you only want "distinctness" on a subset of columns, use `row_Number()`:

```
INSERT INTO Actual_table
    SELECT <col1>, <col2>, . . .
    FROM (SELECT t.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as seqnum
          FROM Temp_table t
         ) t
    WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Sorry if this is a stupid question, but do I have to add 'seqnum' as a column to Actual_table? I'm getting a 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition' error.

Comment: @Alex . . . No, you just need to list out all the columns.  The `*` was a lazy short-cut that doesn't work right in this case.